# conditional statement, if else if

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to write a if, else if condition, with some luck.
after trying for some time I have some of it working but not fully functional.
simple script to change div style for simple image gallery.
I have the first and third divs working but the second is not showing up. 
I seem to understand the concept but in reverse and suspect the problem is in the else if part of the code.
I am not looking for someone to do it for me but to explain where I am reversing things.
Here is what I have working so far, but as I said something is reversed.
any thoughts or better yet explanations would be most appreciated.

```
function scroll()
{
    if (document.getElementById('thumbs1').style.visibility=='hidden' && document.getElementById('thumbs2').style.visibility=='visible' && document.getElementById('thumbs3').style.visibility=='visible' )
    {
      document.getElementById('thumbs1').style.visibility='visible';
      document.getElementById('thumbs2').style.visibility='hidden';
      document.getElementById('thumbs3').style.visibility='hidden';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('thumbs2').style.visibility=='hidden' && document.getElementById('thumbs1').style.visibility=='visible' && document.getElementById('thumbs3').style.visibility=='visible' )
    {
     document.getElementById('thumbs1').style.visibility='hidden';
     document.getElementById('thumbs2').style.visibility='visible';
      document.getElementById('thumbs3').style.visibility='hidden';
    }
    else
    {
     document.getElementById('thumbs1').style.visibility='hidden' ;
     document.getElementById('thumbs2').style.visibility='visible' ;
     document.getElementById('thumbs3').style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: Your problem might be that initially the value is `''`, not `'visible'`.

Comment: It might be easier to do three `if...else if` statements, one for each, rather than one giant `if...else if` statement. If you absolutely have to do it this way though, shouldn't there be more than 3 different cases?

Comment: Your code would be easier to read and more efficient if you store your three "_thumbs_" as 3 different variables.  This has nothing to do with your actual problem, but it will make your code a lot easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, you may be on to something with the more than three cases.

Comment: Jahroy, I suspect that it would be easier with variables but have not gotten the hang of them yet. declaring is easy but then I get all screwes up.

Answer (score 4):

> the second is not showing up

That's because your code never enters the block that shows it. Your condition for that is that `thumbs2` is hidden while `thumbs1` and `thumbs3` are visible, which is a combination that is not apparent in any of the assignments. Seems like you have confused 1 and 3 somewhere.

Tip for spotting such mistakes easier: Create variables for the `style` objects and reuse them instead of executing the code to access them every time. That's not only faster, but also makes the code shorter and more readable. Or even better, an array:

```
var styles = [];
for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
    styles[i] = document.getElementById("thumbs"+(i+1)).style;
```

```
if (styles[0].visibility=='hidden' && styles[1]=='visible' && styles[2].visibility=='visible') {
    styles[0].visibility='visible';
    styles[1].visibility='hidden';
    styles[2].visibility='hidden';
} else if (styles[0].visibility=='visible' && styles[1].visibility=='hidden' && styles[2].visibility=='visible') {
    styles[0].visibility='hidden';
    styles[1].visibility='visible';
    styles[2].visibility='hidden';
} else {
    styles[0].visibility='hidden' ;
    styles[1].visibility='visible' ;
    styles[2].visibility='visible';
}
```

If your pattern had been more predictable (like rotating the visibility), a programmatical approach would be possible as well now.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell what you're trying to do, but if you want to just reverse all 3:

```
 function scroll()
{
    var t1 = document.getElementById('thumbs1'),
        t2 = document.getElementById('thumbs2'),
        t3 = document.getElementById('thumbs3');

       t1.visibility = t1.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden"
       t2.visibility = t2.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden"
       t2.visibility = t3.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden"
}
```

or more succinctly

```
 function scroll()
{
    var thumbs = [document.getElementById('thumbs1'),
        document.getElementById('thumbs2'),
        document.getElementById('thumbs3')];

    for(var i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++) {
       thumbs[i].visibility = thumbs[i].visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually caching the elements (rather than searching for them again and again and again...)

Comment: Thank you, I see the value of the variable and think I understand the grouping of variables. though I am still struggling with the math.

Comment: @E.R.Rider for the second one the for loop starts at 0 and loops through to the end of the array.  Then for each item in the array it checks to see if the visibility is hidden.  If it is, then it changes it to visible, otherwise it changes it to hidden.

Comment: Ok, I am actually starting to see the math here. Though I am not sure the exact method. thumbs[i].visibility = thumbs[i].visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden" this line has me unsure, the first two declarations i think I understand but verification would help.

Comment: I'm thinking that they are conditions to be met and the last part is how to deal with the response.  "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden" first hidden is a question thus the ?, and the last is the answer but how are they decided. i'm thinking that if exactly equal to hidden then the first answer "visible" if not  exactly equal to then "hidden". the semi-colon separates the answers.Maybe?

Comment: I learned somthing, though it dose not work. I DID LEARN SOMETHING. had to shout it out.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks for the thoughts. I found much understanding in the serious thoughts posted here, and i now am beginning to see the appeal of working with arrays. 
The answer was simple and obvious, too many conditions. I used the ideas on variables and used a logical approach. Here is what I came up with.

```
    function scroll()
{
var t1=document.getElementById('thumbs1'), 
       t2=document.getElementById('thumbs2'), 
       t3=document.getElementById('thumbs3');

if (t1.style.visibility=='visible'  )
{
  t2.style.visibility='visible';
  t1.style.visibility='hidden';
  t3.style.visibility='hidden';
}
else if (t2.style.visibility=='visible'  )
{
  t1.style.visibility='hidden';
  t3.style.visibility='visible';
  t2.style.visibility='hidden';
}
else
{
 t1.style.visibility= 'visible';
 t2.style.visibility='hidden' ;
 t3.style.visibility='hidden';
}

}
```

Simple, huh?
Thanks again.
P.S.
would of posted the solution sooner but had to wait 8 hours to answer my own question.